# How do you print an array of strings to console in RISC-V?

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am really confused about how to print arrays of strings to console in RISC-V. I am having trouble finding helpful examples and documentation. I know that you could use ecall with addi, a0,x0, 4, but I can only find examples of the ecall being used to print integers.

Comment: system calls are specific to the system, what (operating) system are you running on?

Comment: please provide a minimal example that completely demonstrates the problem

Comment: what did you find with respect to the calls that you did find relative to the references for the operating system calls for this target?

Answer (score 0):

You can't print an array of strings in any environment I know, such as  simulators like RARS.

However, you can write a loop to identify a single string, one after another, and then print that single string, using ecall 4 to print one string.